# Errors deploying WebApp to Glassfish

Tags: jsf, netbeans, deployment, glassfish, icefaces

** My current problem is listed below, but i've included detail on how I've arrived there **

I'm attempting to deploy a JSF Web Application into Glassfish 3.  Here's a little background about my project in the event any of these details are more relevant than I expected them to be:

- Deploying using NetBeans 7.3.1
- Java Platform: JDK 1.7
- Java EE Version: Java EE 6 Web
- Using ICEFaces components v3.3.
- Development platform is MS Windows.
- Using Apache JENA and OWL API (all libraries are included).

I have the following ICEFaces libraries included in the project:

1. icefaces.jar
2. icepush.jar
3. icefaces-ace.jar
4. icefaces-compat.jar
5. common-logging.jar
6. krysalis-jCharts-1.0.0-alpha-1.jar
7. jxl.jar

When I first attempted to deploy my application, I received the following exception:

```
javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactoryConfigurationError: Provider  
org.apache.xalan.processor.TransformerFactoryImpl not found at
javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at org.openide.xml.XMLUtil.write(XMLUtil.java:428)
```

After reading several response here as well as around the web, I went ahead and added the file "xml-apis-1.4.01.jar" to the GLASSFISH_HOME\glassfish\modules\endorsed directory.  During my next deployment attempt, I received the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.GlassFishMain.main(GlassFishMain.java:97)
at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.ASMain.main(ASMain.java:55)
Caused by: javax.xml.stream.FactoryConfigurationError: Provider com.ctc.wstx.stax.WstxInputFactory not found
at javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory.newInstance(Unknown Source)
```

Which prompted me to do more research and eventually add "stax2-api-3.1.1.jar" to the GLASSFISH_HOME\glassfish\modules\endorsed directory.  Unfortunately, this is where my research luck ran out.  I am now receiving the following exception:

```
WARNING: Failed to install file:GLASSFISH_HOME/glassfish/modules/endorsed/stax2-api-3.1.1.jar
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Bundle symbolic name and version are not unique: stax2-api:3.1.1
at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleImpl.createRevision(BundleImpl.java:1230)
at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleImpl.<init>(BundleImpl.java:95)
at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.installBundle(Felix.java:2732)
at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleContextImpl.installBundle(BundleContextImpl.java:165)
at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.BundleProvisioner.install(BundleProvisioner.java:446)
at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.BundleProvisioner.installBundles(BundleProvisioner.java:208)
at
com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.OSGiGlassFishRuntimeBuilder.build(OSGiGlassFishRuntimeBuilder.java:139)
at org.glassfish.embeddable.GlassFishRuntime._bootstrap(GlassFishRuntime.java:157)
at org.glassfish.embeddable.GlassFishRuntime.bootstrap(GlassFishRuntime.java:110)
at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.GlassFishMain$Launcher.launch(GlassFishMain.java:112)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.GlassFishMain.main(GlassFishMain.java:97)
at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.ASMain.main(ASMain.java:55)
```

Now, I am not explicitly using any Woodstox components in this project, so I'm at a loss for why Glassfish requires this.  At first, I thought I did something wrong, so I went ahead and uninstalled and re-installed the Glassfish instance and recreated the domain.  Still this requirement remains when I try to deploy the project.

Any advice?

As always, thank you all very much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

So after doing a bunch more research and toying around with the setup, I think I have solved the problem.  First, here's a bit of background on my process.

Since I had never used Woodstox components in my project, I assumed that there was a dependency on the aforementioned jars in one of my included libraries.  I figured I'd completely remove Glassfish and re-install to try the "clean slate" approach.  Unfortunately, this did not work and I continued to have the same exception.

I ended up searching the entire drive for Felix jars and directories and deleted everything I could find.  I then attempted to re-start Glassfish which (expectedly) ended in an error stating Felix could not be found.  I then did a clean un-install and re-install, and everything worked.  My only thought is that something was cached and it was not being overwritten.

This corrected the last exception I reported, but unfortunately, I still experienced the former.  My only thought at this time (based on quite a bit of searching) is that the OWL Library's XML parser doesn't play nicely with Glassfish.